# multiple IF conditions, the result being one of several calculations--Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to apply a different multiple depending on where a number falls in a specific range.
For example:

```
IF >1000000 is the base, THEN base minus 1000000, multiplied by .015+25000
IF >150000<1000000 is the base, THEN base multiplied by .025
IF <150000 is the base, THEN base multiplied by .030
```

This is what I came up with (b5=base):

```
=IF(b5>1000000),(B5-1000000)*0.015+250000,IF(B5>150000<1000000),B5*0.025,IF(B5<150000),B5*0.03
```

What am I missing? mb

Comment: You can't do the double compare of B5 in the statement: `B5>150000<1000000` You don't need the second comparison as you're already checking for that earlier anyways.

Comment: You may get some odd results around the 150,000 breakpoint doing this as you set out here - for a value of 150,000 in B5 the formula will result in 4500, add 1 to get 150,001 and result dips down to 3775....you have to go back up to 180,000 for the result to reach 4500 again - is that your intent?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with this formula:

```
=IF(B5>1000000,(B5-1000000)*0.015+25000,
 IF(B5>150000,B5*0.025,
 B5*0.03))
```

Note that your question is not consistent - you might need to replace `+25000` with `*25000`!

Comment: While this should work, as I said in the comment above, you don't need to check if it's less than 1000000 again since it's already been checked.

Comment: @KronoS: Good point. I saw it for the second "Else" - but missed the first one. Answer is updated.

Comment: I also updated yours (and the OP's) value.  Since 1000000 > 150000 this works, but your original code had 10000 which is < 150000 and would always be executed before ever reaching the second else condition.  This was an issue with the OP and not you :P

Comment: Hello Peter - I think you need 0.025 and 0.03 as multipliers if the question is correct

Comment: @barryhoudini: Well spotted, thanks! Answer is updated.